# Modifying /etc/fstab to make the mount -a command work

Tags: mount, fstab

So I've made a new image for our linux machines but i need to modify the new `/etc/fstab` file to be able to use the command `mount -a` to mount the specific address using username/password found in the old `/etc/fstab` file.

What do i need to do in-order to get this to work the same as the older system.
I was given this method on how to read files off a local PC and I know changing these files will cause a system failure (at least when i tried using the previous file)

The old fstab file looks like this

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=########-####-####-####-############ /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=########-####-####-####-############ none            swap    sw              0       0
//192.168.0.10/data /mnt/db cifs ro,iocharset=utf8,username=#####,password=##### 0 0
```

Where as the new file looks like this

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=########-####-####-####-############ /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I want to use the last line from old file (below) in the new file but im not sure what else is needed from the old one to make this work when using the `sudo mount -a` command

`//192.168.0.10/data /mnt/db cifs ro,iocharset=utf8,username=######,password=##### 0 0`

Comment: @AndyDalton No problem, modified the post to incorporate the text of the files.

Comment: Thank you.  Is the CIFS share the only thing that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Yes, i just want to know if adding the last line to the new `fstab` file will work on its own or if it needed any of the other lines from the old `fstab` file

Comment: Your new mount line is basically correct, but what problem are you having? Why the question? It either works, or it throws an error. I would also recommend adding file mode and dir mode to make Windows files not appear executable, but I don't know your use case, so please explain what you need to achieve and what is the problem.

Comment: @ajeh The new file is the base file from the ubuntu image, i havent added anything to it. I wanted to know if the last line from the old file would work on the new file. And I cant test it locally at the moment so i want to make sure it wont bring the computer down if i mess up the `fstab` file

Comment: `man mount` then. Adding `nofail` option would ensure the boot continues even if remote FS is not mountable. It used to be called `nobootwait` which was more explicit about the intent, but gremlins changed that. You might want to put the credentials into an external file to avoid having to censor them every time you ask a question about this line.

Comment: Changing `/etc/fstab` won’t crash the system.  Changing `/etc/fstab` and then running ``mount -a`` *might* cause a problem.  If you change `/etc/fstab`, the next boot might have problems.  Do you know how to boot into “single user” mode?  Learn.  Then edit `/etc/fstab` and run `mount -a`.  If it hangs or crashes the system, use “single user” mode to fix it.  But, if you take a `mount` command that works from the shell and put it into `/etc/fstab`, you’ll probably be OK.

Comment: @G-Man Wrong entries in `fstab` can prevent the system from completing the boot process. Commands that work from the shell use a different state of the devices than entries in `fstab`.

Comment: @ajeh: I did say “probably”. If you understand this issue so well, I suggest that you post an answer. (That’s considered to be more helpful than telling the OP to read the manual.)